# Is there a way to track changes on two tables using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have a problem I was hoping someone here could help me with. I have 2 tables (old and new) with very similar data (equal columns and number of rows), but with a few differences in some values. I would like to track the differences in values (data) between these 2 tables. My thought is to use `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` both of which are not giving the result I would like. It should be noted that the ID which would normally be the primary key does not contain unique values (I added a Serial_Number column to solve this). I really just need to see the values that have changed. From the images, you will notice that there the differences in the Staff_ID and Amount on 5 and 6. There are instances where the Staff_ID is the same but the Amount has changed.

Approach 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM Database_2
LEFT JOIN Database_1 
ON  Database_2.Staff_ID = Database_1.Staff_ID
```

Approach 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Database_2
INNER JOIN Database_1 
ON  Database_2.Staff_ID = Database_1.Staff_ID
```

Approach 3: (I added a Serial_Number column. This is not even working)

```
SELECT Serial_Number, Staff_ID, PT, Price  FROM Database_1 
EXCEPT
SELECT Serial_Number, Staff_ID, PT, Price from Database_2;
```

Here is a sample of the data. You will observe that there are differences (staff_id and amount) in rows 5 and 6. There are other rows that have just changes in the amount.

A minimal reproducible:

```
CREATE TABLE DB1 (
    `Serial_Number` INT,
    `Staff_ID` INT,
    `Price` INT,
    `Percentage` NUMERIC(3, 2),
    `Change` VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET utf8
);
INSERT INTO DB1 VALUES
    (1,53441,NULL,0.05,'Y'),
    (2,53441,NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (3,12855,500,NULL,NULL),
    (4,12855,NULL,NULL,'Y'),
    (5,2005511,NULL,NULL,'Y'),
    (6,839123,1300,NULL,NULL);
    
CREATE TABLE DB2 (
    `Serial_Number` INT,
    `Staff_ID` INT,
    `Price` INT,
    `Percentage` NUMERIC(3, 2),
    `Change` VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET utf8
);
INSERT INTO DB2 VALUES
    (1,53441,NULL,0.05,NULL),
    (2,53441,550,NULL,'Y'),
    (3,12855,500,NULL,NULL),
    (4,12855,NULL,NULL,'Y'),
    (5,2005511,600,NULL,'Y'),
    (6,839123,1300,NULL,NULL)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. Is your question about [ms-access] or [sql-server]?, because you tagged both.

Comment: @McNets Either or both will be appreciated

Comment: Could you post some sample data you're working with? Preferably as DDL statements so we can hit the ground running.

Comment: @MichaelBruesch I have added screenshots of the sample data to the question. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to compare records across the two tables with the same Serial_Number?

Comment: Add a [mcve] showing the exact table definitions with representative sample data.  Are you attempting to see the differences between rows in the two tables?

Comment: Also, please choose only one DBMS for this question.

Comment: @MichaelBruesch Yes, I want to compare the records for the differences between both tables.

Comment: @HannahVernon Thank you for the suggestion, I have now added a code block. Yes, I am trying to see the differences between the rows in the two tables.

Comment: Don't you have some indexes?  At least a `PRIMARY KEY`?  Is `staff_id` the column on which you need to compare the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, merge the two tables into one "from" block via a Union All.
Then group by all of the columns, so you can count how many rows match on all columns.
Then exclude all rows with a count of 2 (the rows match between both tables).

Setup the tables based on your image captures:

```
create table database_1 (
    Serial_number int not null identity primary key,
    Staff_id int not null,
    [Source] varchar(20),
    Country varchar(20),
    Currency varchar(20),
    Payment_type varchar(20),
    Payment_Order int,
    Price numeric(9,2)
    );

create table database_2 (
    Serial_number int not null identity primary key,
    Staff_id int not null,
    [Source] varchar(20),
    Country varchar(20),
    Currency varchar(20),
    Payment_type varchar(20),
    Payment_Order int,
    Price numeric(9,2)
    );
```

Insert your screen capture data:

```
insert into database_1 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (53441, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 1, null);
insert into database_1 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (53441, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 2, null);
insert into database_1 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (12855, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 1, 500);
insert into database_1 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (12855, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 2, null);
insert into database_1 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (2005511, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 1, 2000);
insert into database_1 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (456551, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 1, null);

insert into database_2 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (53441, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 1, null);
insert into database_2 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (53441, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 2, null);
insert into database_2 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (12855, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 1, 500);
insert into database_2 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (12855, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 2, null);
insert into database_2 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (2005511, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 1, null);
insert into database_2 (Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price) Values (456551, 'BOY', 'CAN', 'CAD', 'E-CAD', 1, 1300);
```

merge the two tables into one select

```
select Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price
             from database_1  
 union all
select Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price
             from database_2
```

Merge matching rows and exclude all rows that match in both tables:

```
select  Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price, count(*) [RowCount]
  from (
       select Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price
         from database_1  
        union all
       select Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price
         from database_2 
       ) a
 group by  Staff_id, [Source], Country, Currency, Payment_type, Payment_Order, price
having count(*) = 1
```

If the row count value is 1, then it exists in 1 of the two tables but not the other. If the row count is 2, then it exists the same in both tables. The Having count =1 means we're excluding everything that matches across all columns.

[image: Results screen shot]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This will provide you any rows that are different between the two tables and label which row belongs to which.  The first part of the query gets all rows from `Database_1` that aren't in `Database_2`, and the second portion gets all rows from `Database_2` that aren't in `Database_1`.

```
SELECT
 DataSource = 'Database_1'
,Serial_Number
,Staff_Id
,Source
,Country
,Currency
,Payment_Type
,Payment_Order
,Price
FROM 
  Database_1

  EXCEPT

SELECT
 'Database_1'
,Serial_Number
,Staff_Id
,Source
,Country
,Currency
,Payment_Type
,Payment_Order
,Price
FROM
  Database_2

  UNION ALL

SELECT
 'Database_2'
,Serial_Number
,Staff_Id
,Source
,Country
,Currency
,Payment_Type
,Payment_Order
,Price
FROM 
  Database_2

  EXCEPT

SELECT
 'Database_2'
,Serial_Number
,Staff_Id
,Source
,Country
,Currency
,Payment_Type
,Payment_Order
,Price
FROM
  Database_1
```

So this is useful from a "just get me the rows" perspective, but it may be helpful to view the values side by side.  There needs to be a primary key between the two sources, I'm assuming `Serial_Number` for the purpose of this example.

```
SELECT
  Combined.Serial_Number
 ,Db1_Staff_Id = DB1.Staff_Id
 ,Db2_Staff_Id = DB2.Staff_Id
 ,Db1_Source = DB1.Source
 ,Db2_Source = DB2.Source
  /* Rest of the columns here */
 ,Db1_Price = DB1.Price
 ,Db2_Price = DB2.Price
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Serial_Number
    FROM
      Database_1

      UNION

   SELECT
     Serial_Number
    FROM
      Database_2
  ) Combined
LEFT JOIN
  Database_1 DB1
    ON DB1.Serial_Number = Combined.Serial_Number
LEFT JOIN
  Database_2 DB2
    ON DB2.Serial_Number = Combined.Serial_Number
WHERE 
  NOT
    (
      Db1.Staff_Id = Db2.Staff_Id
        AND Db1.Source = Db2.Source
        /* Rest of columns */
        AND COALESCE(Db1.Price,-1) = COALESCE(Db2.Price,-1)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful.